# Trying to create MySql DB with Nhibernate - need some direction

Tags: mysql, nhibernate

So I am very new to web development and working on a new project that will make use of Nhibernate as my ORM and MySql database.

I wanted to set it up so that NHibernate would create my database table based on the (all necessary NHibernate files).  So far I have concluded that NHibernate will generate the DB schema that I have laid out with the mappings and class files.

The problem I am seeing is that it appears that you must have the database in place in MySql first for NHibernate to create the table (understood).  However, when reviewing creating a MySql database in the manual it is requiring you to specify the schema with the create command.

So far the number of blogs I have read concentrate on what you need for NHibernate and not much details in correctly prepping your MySql server.

Any direction or advise is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run the "create database [databasename];" command before building up your schema. You don't neeed to specify a schema to use this command.

Comment: is it required to specify your properties in the persistent class as "virtual".

Comment: Nhibernate creates proxies from your classes and to do so it needs to overrride the properties in your classes. Therefore, your properties must be virtual.